# Не запускается CodeIgniter на локальном компьютере

Tags: denwer, codeigniter

Сделал всё правильно, создал нужные папки, запускаю в браузере, пишет **"Страница не найдена"**.

Comment: Звать экстрасенсов...

Comment: напиши что куда скопировал и файл конфига выложи.

Answer (score 1):

Мало что указал конкретно. Но как я понял: Зайди в пупку config и редактируй файл routes.
Присвой роуту default_controller название контроллера, который будешь считать по умолчанию. Создай контроллер с этим именем, создай вид и выводи этот вид в контроллере.

Answer (score 1):

1. Поставь нормальную локальную сборку - [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)
2. Пропиши в конфиге параметры:

   ```
   $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/dedal/';
   $config['index_page'] = '';
   ```
3. **Разберись с файлом .htaccess**